# Error in R `psych::polychoric` for factor analysis

Tags: r, categorical-data, psych, factor-analysis

I'm having some difficulty running a factor analysis of
polychoric correlations in **psych**. I think I've narrowed the problem down to the function `polychoric()`. Here's a small example:

```r
df <- data.frame(a = c(1, 3, 2), 
                 b = c(1, 2, 1), 
                 c = c(2, 1, 3))
psych::polychoric(df)
```

```
Error in cor(x, use = "pairwise") : 
  supply both 'x' and 'y' or a matrix-like 'x'
...
```

plus other warnings that have to do with the data frame `df`.
I get this output whether `df` is a data frame or matrix, and whether the variables are numeric or factor.

The help page `?polychoric` says this about the first argument `x`:

> The input may be in one of four forms:
>
> a) a data frame or matrix of dichotomous data (e.g., the lsat6 from the bock data set) or discrete numerical (i.e., not too many levels, e.g., the big 5 data set, bfi) for polychoric, or continuous for the case of biserial and polyserial.
>
> ...

The Usage section says that the second argument `y` can be `NULL`, which is what I would expect in a factor analysis when I supply a data frame `x`.

I need to get this working because it's used with `fa()` and `irt.fa()` to calculate the reliability of factors.

Comment: Your data is in the wrong format, it's not dichotomous. Look at the `lsat` dataset for example. This works: `x <- sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE); y <- sample(letters[1:3], 10, replace = TRUE); tab <- table(x,y); polychoric(tab, smooth = TRUE)`

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! I don't think it's the wrong format: in [this how-to](https://personality-project.org/r/psych/HowTo/factor.pdf), the bfi dataset is used and it is not a frequency table. Also, I have over 50 items in my real data so table() doesn't work.

Comment: You're right about that! Your example works with different numbers: `df <- data.frame(a = c(2, 2, 5), b = c(4, 4, 4),  c = c(3, 5, 5))` which I took from `bfi[1:3,1:3]`. I don't know anything about the package so don't know what's going on.

Comment: Thank you; I'll respond below when I figure it out.